# Filter Windows directory by file type

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Imagine a large number of files, organized in folders (thousands of folders)...there are multiple types of files in each folder (PDF, ZIP, DOCX, etc.).  I'm looking for a tool that can show the current directory structure, but just the type(s) of files that I want to see (just the PDFs for instance).  The ability to copy the displayed files to another location and just get the file type(s) I'm looking for would be nice also.

Any suggestions?

I can set a backup tool to create a new directory structure that mimics what I want, but that's both time and space intensive.

Win7 or Win8

Comment: Given thousands of folders, the command line is probably more powerful than an organised view. `dir` can be used to only show files with a certain extension. You can use `for` to execute commands on them. You can even very quickly and space-efficiently build a new directory structure with symbolic links. Simple file operations like `robocopy` can filter filetypes directly. What exactly do you want to do with these files?

Answer (score 0):

Windows PowerShell and the Command line have many commands that you can use to move through the directory tree, such as CD to change the directory, DIR to list the directory contents, and you can combine wild cards to search for any file of a particular type. As an example, use DIR *.PDF to find all pdf files within that directory. If there are a lot of files, pipe it to the MORE command to view the list one page at a time. You can also move and copy files  in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Dropit might work well for what you want to do as well: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dropit/?source=frontpage&position=10